# DateTime format error in python while using aiofiles

Tags: python, datetime

These are my timestamp logs:

```
2023-02-16 21:38:59,873 : Device was cradled
2023-02-16 21:38:59,873 : Device connected to network, IP
```

I was trying to get them sorted with this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
sorted(files, key=lambda file: dt.strptime(file.split()[0],
                                           "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

and getting an error:

```
ValueError: time data '2023-02-16' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: Indeed, `2023-02-16` does not match `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`, because it is only a date and does not have hours:minutes:seconds.

Comment: Your call to `split()` separates the line into fields on whitespace. Since there's space between the date and time, they wind up in separate fields. But you're only grabbing the first one (`[0]`), which has just the date.

Comment: Without seeing the code, it seems like you have two options: add hours:minutes:seconds onto the `2023-02-16` string, or remove `%H:%M:%S` from the required format.

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off installing one of the many log-parsing modules available instead of rolling your own, but in this case you can sort properly just by changing your `split` call.

For example, if your sample data is accurate, then there's a colon with space on either side of it between the timestamp and the log message, so you can split on that instead of space:

```
sorted(files, key=lambda line: dt.strptime(line.split(' : ')[0],
                                           '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%f'))
```